# What is wrong with this NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface PINQuote : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *lines;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *quoteID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customerName;
@end
```

When I try:
    PINQuote *quote = [[PINQuote alloc] init];
    [quote.lines addObject:@"TEST STRING"];

the array is still nil.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't magically create itself when you initialize the object. You need to assign the *array* a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following to the implementation:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)lines
{
    if (!_lines) // Lazy load the mutable array when asked for.
        _lines = [NSMutableArray array];
    return _lines;
}
```

or if you don't like lazy loading:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _lines = [NSMutableArray array]; // Eager load the mutable array.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have only declared the property. You must now create it. Try lazy instantiation:

**PINQuote.m**

```
- (NSMutableArray*)lines {
    if (!_lines)
        _lines = [NSMutableArray array];
    return _lines;
}
```